# Is it possible to disable scripts depending upon media queries in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really wondering if this is possible.

Right now I'm designing a new personal website for myself with HTML5/CSS3, and I found some nice javascripts to execute on my site such as snowing effects and so forth. They work perfect on big size screens like my laptop, but on my mobile phone, they just go crazy.

I've been using media queries to make my website responsive and I thought like maybe I could stop these scripts from working on small sized screens with some sort of 'disable code' or something in media queries. I'm not obsessed with these scripts of course, but some of them are really nice and useful and I'd be really glad if I could sort this problem out without losing them.

By the way, I'm also using Bootstrap so I need javascript running, so turning all the scripts off would be impossible for me. I just need to disable some specific ones.

I'd really appreciate your helps. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **Javascript** you can do it with something like this:

```
if (screen.width < 600) {
        // don’t download complicated script
        // use low-source images instead of full-source ones
}

else{
   //let's see the snowflakes()!
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! I didn't use that else statement though, I just encapsulated the executing part of the script with screen.width > 600 statement. And I don't know what's wrong but at first I tried window.width but it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on depending  on Media Queries, there is a javascript library you can use, [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/). Example from website

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 40em)", {
    match : function() {
        // Load sidebar content in via AJAX.
        // Show sidebar
    },  
    unmatch : function() {
        // Hide the sidebar
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can remove it from JS. It will be the same.

```
$(function(){
    if (window.width < 600) {

    }
});
```